# Root transformation to make normalized coefficient match

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Let $f(x) = \prod_{i=0}^n(1+a_ix), a_i \neq 0$, and $C(f(x)): = (c_0, c_i, \cdots, c_n) $, where $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$.

For a given monomial $g(x) = (1+mx)(1+nx)$, i'm interested in a quantity $\langle C(g), \frac{1}{C((1+x)^2)} \rangle$. Here $\langle, \rangle$ is the inner product and $\frac{1}{.}$ is element-wise reciprocal.

And my question is, is there any non-trivial mapping$(m_1, m_2 \neq 1)$, $h: m \to (m_1, m_2)$, such that

$\langle C((1+mx)(1+nx)), \frac{1}{C((1+x)^2} \rangle = \langle C((1+m_1x)(1+m_2x)(1+nx)), \frac{1}{C((1+x)^3} \rangle$ ?

Comment: Is the $h$ supposed to be independent of $n$? If so, there is no such $h$.

Comment: not necessary. but I'm also interested in the independent case.

Comment: and in my true setting  $(1+nx)$ might be a high order polynomial, e.g. $(1+nx)(1+px)(1+qx)$ but then they will carry over to the $m_1, m_2$ setting

Comment: I was going to say that I suspected that this is not the original problem, but something you extracted out of some other problem. I think it is better to post the original problem, the true setting.

Comment: @Boxwood this is the full problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319943/determine-if-a-function-is-monotonic and I was exploring ways to normalize the result, so that it's a constant regardless how I split the roots into portitions

Comment: In order for your inner product to make sense, the polynomials provided to $C$ must have the same degree. That works when $g$ is quadratic as is $(1+x)^2$. But $(1+m_1x)(1+m_2x)(1+nx)$ is cubic and is converted to a point in $\Bbb R^4$, while $1/C((1+x)^2)$ remains in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: the "normalizing" polynomial becomes  $1/C((1+x)^3)$ in the cubic case @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want $$1 + \frac{m+n}2 +mn = 1 + \frac{m_1 + m_2 +n}3 + \frac{m_1m_2 + m_1n + m_2n}3 + m_1m_2n\,?$$
You can solve that for $m_2$ in terms of the other variables
$$m_2 = \frac{3m + n + 6mn - 2m_1 - 2m_1n}{2 + 2m_1 + 2n + 6m_1n}$$

So you can choose whatever function $m \mapsto m_1$ you want, and find the corresponding $m_2$ per the equation to build $h$. If $m_1$ is not a trivial function of $m$, neither will $h$ be trivial. As Boxwood already noted, it isn't going to be independent of $n$.

A similar calculation can be done for any degree $g$.

Comment: Thanks! do you mind taking a look at my original question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319943/determine-if-a-function-is-monotonic ? basically if without any transformation is this function ever-decreasing?  with all the variables $\gt 1$.